# Make part of a regex match in python optional

Tags: python, regex, match

I'm trying to match a URL using `re` but am having trouble in regards to making part of the match optional.

```
import re

x = raw_input('Link: ')
reg = '(http|https)://(iski|www\.iskis|iskis)\.(in|com)/[A-Za-z0-9?&=/?_]+'
if re.match(reg, x):
    print 'True'
```

Currently, the above code would match something like:

```
https://iskis.com/?loc=shop_view_item&item=220503032
```

I would like to alter the regular expression to make the following, `[A-Za-z0-9?&=/?_]+` an option - As such, anything after the slash isn't required, so the following should match:

```
https://iskis.com
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution but I don't know how to go about solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reg = '(http|https)://(iski|www\.iskis|iskis)\.(in|com)(/[A-Za-z0-9?&=/?_]+)?$'
```

Should do it. Surround the character class with `()` so it's a group, put a `?` after it to make the text match 0-1 instances of that group, and put a `$` at the end so that the regex will match to the end.

EDIT:

Come to think of it, you could use the optional match elsewhere in your regex.

```
reg = '(https?)://(www\.)?(iskis?)\.(in|com)(/[A-Za-z0-9?&=/?_]+)?$'
```